# Transposed Convolution 2D parameter choice

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I'd like to generate an image of size (176,132), from a (60,1) Vector.

I don't know how to choose the Stride, Kernels, Padding and output paddings to best fit my problem... Is there any online resource that could help ?

I believe stacking a few TransposedConvolution2D layers helps, but how do each layer's parameters relate to each other ? Should they go increasing or decreasing ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This paper contains some formulas that relate convolutional layer parameters to input and output shapes: [A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep
learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf)

Comment: I've read it, but I'd like to know how to choose the optimal parameters.

Comment: Unfourtanetly, you have to calculate them by the formulas ...